# How to encode a PDF to a binary in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, pdf

I am trying to make an document scanner app in flutter where whenever a user clicks a button the PDF that is already created should be added to an SQLite database .For uploading a PDF into a SQLite database in flutter we need to convert the file to a binary.But I don't know how to do that please help me.The code for converting a image to a pdf

```
  String _status = "Not created";
  File pdfFile;

  FileStat _pdfStat;

bool _generating = false;   


Future<File> _assetFromBundle(String name) async {
final tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final output = File(path.join(tempDir.path, name));

if (!await output.exists()) {
  final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/$name');
  final buffer = data.buffer;
  output.writeAsBytes(
      buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
}

return output;
}

 Future<void> _createPdf() async {
  try {
   this.setState(() => _generating = true);
  final tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final output = File(path.join(tempDir.path, 'example.pdf'));

  this.setState(() => _status = 'Preparing images...');
  final images = [ff.image];

  this.setState(() => _status = 'Generating PDF');
  await ImagesToPdf.createPdf(
    pages: images
        .map(
          (file) => PdfPage(
             imageFile: file,
            compressionQuality: 0.5,
           ) , 
         )
         .toList(),
     output: output,
    );
     _pdfStat = await output.stat();
    this.setState(() {
     pdfFile = output;
    _status = 'PDF Generated (${_pdfStat.size ~/ 1024}kb)';
    });
} catch (e) {
  this.setState(() => _status = 'Failed to generate pdf: $e".');
} finally {
  this.setState(() => _generating = false);
 }
}

  Future<void> _openPdf() async {
  if (pdfFile != null) {
  try {
      final bytes = await pdfFile.readAsBytes();
       await Printing.sharePdf(
          bytes: bytes, filename: path.basename(pdfFile.path));
     } catch (e) {
    _status = 'Failed to open pdf: $e".';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is bytes, use File class to read as bytes,

```
var f = File('file/path.pdf');
List<int> binaries = await f.readAsBytes();
```

use the bytes as is or by encoding it to Base64 String

`var asString = Base64Codec().encode(binaries);`

Comment: When i try to pass the pdf that has already been created it throws up an error saying "The argument type file can't be assigned to a parameter type String" .You also have used await without a async

Comment: post the code, yes the await should be inside a asynchronous function or else the linter will throw

Comment: somewhere you are assigning a File to a String!, check the error line

Comment: I have posted the code that i used to convert a image into a pdf in the question itself.I passed the File pdfFile which of type  file into the code var f = File('file/path.pdf');
List<int> binaries = await f.readAsBytes();

Comment: On that line either your trying to assign a file to string or calling a method by passing File where string should be passed

Comment: i am trying to assign a file to a string

Comment: Please comment the line where you trying to assign (in the question)

Comment: File pdfFile
the second line in the code and when i want to use it like var f = File(pdfFile); List<int> binaries = await f.readAsBytes().It is throwing an error

Comment: Put a semicolon ; after File pdfFile

Comment: Error states you what you should do, post more runnable code, or a screenshot